# Как перевести слово "evaluate" на русский как термин программирования?

Tags: переводы

Как перевести слово "evaluate" на русский как термин программирования? Я даже будучи носителем языка не могу понять как. Иногда можно "выполняется" или "вычисляется". Пример:

> First `condition` is *evaluated*, then exactly one of either `a` or `b` is *evaluated* and returned based on the [Boolean][4] value of `condition`. If `condition` *evaluates to* `True`, then `a` is *evaluated* and returned but `b` is ignored, or else when `b` is *evaluated* and returned but `a` is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно в переводах используется вариант *"вычисляется"* во всех случаях.
Да, это порой порождает такие непривычные для "не программистов" формулировки, как *"если условие вычисляется в True"*, но практически в каждой узкоспециальной сфере деятельности есть устоявшиеся выражения, порой способные повергнуть в шок стороннего читателя.

Если вы готовы пожертвовать дословностью перевода ради благозвучия, попробуйте немного изменить формулировку. Например, приведенный выше фрагмент можно трансформировать в *"если результатом вычисления условного выражения является значение True"*.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо! Перевожу ответ с en.SO для ru.SO.

Comment: *"если условие вычисляется в True"* -  если условие вычисляется **как** True. Это решает б**о**льшую часть проблем.

Comment: @behemothus, "вычисляется как True" - это перевод немножко другого словосочетания: "evaluate as 'True'", в то время как "вычисляется в True" - перевод "evaluates to True". Разумеется, оба варианта близки, поэтому возможность или невозможность их взаимной замены определяется исключительно требованиями к степени дословности перевода.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты есть, по контексту: имеет значение, преобразуется, соответствует, выражается в  и проч.

В вашем фрагменте я не вижу причин отвеггаать дословный перевод именно этого слова (хотя предложенный в ответе @IvanOlshansky, конечно, выглядит более "благозвучным").

> First condition is evaluated, then exactly one of either a or b is
> evaluated and returned based on the [Boolean][4] value of condition.
> If condition evaluates to True, then a is evaluated and returned but b
> is ignored, or else when b is evaluated and returned but a is ignored.

Сначала вычисляется "условие", затем вычисляется и оценивается одно из значений **a** или **b** в зависимости от вычисленного с типом [Boolean][4] значения условия. Если условие вычислено как **True**, тогда вычисляется и возвращается **a**, а **b** игнорируется, иначе **b** оценивается и возвращается, а **а** игнорируется.

ПС в такой формулировке, на мой вкус, до неприличия много лишних слов, но тут уж ничего не поделаешь, если так изъясняются в оригинальном английском тексте. А вот что касается "условия с типом [Boolean][4]", тут пришлось слегка поправить формулировку, чтобы сделать её хоть сколько-нибудь вменяемой.

Answer (score 1):

Универсальный смысл этого слова в матем. контексте - "**дать количественную оценку**" чему-либо. Здесь в одном случае получают *двоичное значение* по факту выполнения или невыполнения "условия" ("*оценивают*" его выполнение), а в другом - *вычисляют* величины а или в. В переводе буквальные значения слов не всегда полезны, важнее правильно передать исходный смысл средствами русского языка (с его порядком слов и т. п.). Предлагаемый вариант:

> *Сначала оценивается выполнение условия; затем, в зависимости от двоичного значения [4] оценки выполнения условия, вычисляется
> конкретно одна из двух величин - **a** или **b**. Если оценкой выполнения
> условия оказывается True [=логичекая единица], то вычисляется и
> возвращается [=выводится как результат] величина **а**, а величина **b**
> игнорируется, в противном случае [=выполнение условия оценивается как
> False, логичекий нуль] вычисляется **b**, а величина **а** игнорируется.*

Comment: Ваш перевод звучит немножко странно мне кажется, извните ;)

Comment: Вероятно, вы отнесли к тексту перевода комментарии в квадратных скобках. Технический смысл совсем прост: если условие выполняется, то в результате операции вычисляется **a**, а если не выполняеся, то вычисляется **в**. Кстати, применительно к "условию" evaluates можно перевести и как "проверяется".